# Forge ARKit: Cannot load model in Unity

Tags: autodesk-forge

With the latest ForgeARKit-update-6-2018.1, I was trying to load my model in Unity, with the sample Unity scene '**loadAtStartup**'. I can successfully load the sample models from 'Sandbox', but I couldn't load my model, which was uploaded through script '**test-2legged**'.

**Error message** shows 504, it seems not reaching the service:

> *AsyncRequestCompleted The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Time-out.
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   Autodesk.Forge.ARKit.RequestQueueMgr:AsyncRequestCompleted(Object, AsyncCompletedEventArgs) (at Assets/Forge/CodeBase/RequestQueue.cs:322)
>   UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:ExecuteTasks()*

**Model URN:**
dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bWFvbGlua3ppOHM3cnlvZWx4bjVndnR4bjcyZWc2N2l0dGp0a2MvMmZsb29yX0FyYy5pZmM=

**[Update 23/4/2019]**
I found that I can successfully load the same model with ForgeARKit-update-3-2017.1.2f1. I compare the Forge code in Unity. I think it has something to do with the service URL. The version 6 is fetching models from 'https://developer-api-**beta**.autodesk.io' while version 3 is fetching from 'https://developer-api.autodesk.io'. Meanwhile the shell script 'test-2legged' is uploading to the latter one ('https://developer-api.autodesk.io'). That is why it counldn'd find the resource. Question here is how can I upload model to the 'beta' ARKit? I tried modifying the URL in script 'test-2legged' but it doesn't work. Below screen-shot is the output of script 'test-2legged' when fetching from 'beta' ARkit. It seems model is uploaded successfully, but some parsing post-work failed. I guess the response format is also changed in the beta version. Is there a beta version of 'test-2legged' scripts (and other Scene Preparation scripts)?
[image]

Please comments, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. My apologizes for this, I know we did not documented very well on the server changes.

This update6 assumes you are using the new server under beta right now. The scripts and update 3 are using the legacy server. Note that the 2 servers are not necessarily compatible and store the data in different places, so make sure to always use the same server in Unity as the one you used to prepare the scene. When we will switch everyone to the new server, we will transfer the data from the legacy server to the new server cloud storage.

The Update3 package will still be able to read scenes from the new server, as we make sure the old Unity code stays compatible.

Note as well you need to use SafeBase64 encoded string everywhere. I saw in your description that you are using base64 encoded (not safe). The new server will be more strict of parameters and format, so I encourage you to test your scripts/code on the beta server.

Last, I am working on a new Unity code update, and documentation which will be released next week. Make sure to use this version - it adds support for 3legged, automatic 2/3legged token refresh, and more. If you got scenes failing, please contact me directly and share your models and URN. I'll either test it on my development environment, or look into our log files for the reason to fail. My email address is my first name at autodesk.com

Comment: Could you please find my response below?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cyrille for your help!! I am replying you here as it's easier to insert images.

I replaced the function '*xbase64encode()*' with '*xbase64safeencode()*', and now it works! However it seems for some model it still responds some error and in that case it cannot be loaded in Unity. (as the image below). I checked the script and I think all the encoding are using SafeBase64. Any clue of that? Or is that caused by my model?
[image]
[image]

BTW, the loading performance is greatly improved than the legacy version!! It looks almost the same as the web client. Huge Thanks for that!

Good to know that there is going to be an update next week. Yes I will test it and get back to you later.

Comment: I just pushed a new server version. The scripts you are using needs to be updated. These errors are jq errors, but not the Forge toolkit errors. The payload returned may have changed a bit for these tests scripts to work properly. I'll send you my latest scripts by email.