# Model incomplete when loading with Forge AR/VR Toolkit

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-arvr

I have an IFC model, and I use the sample script 'test-2legged' in Scene Preparation (http://forgetoolkit.com/#/scenePrepration) to upload it to Forge. Then I loaded it with AR/VR toolkit (ForgeARKit-update-6-2018.1). However the downloaded model is incomplete (see below pictures). There is no external links in the model.

Please also note that I did some minor modification in 'test-2legged', as the original sample does not work directly with the new beta server 'https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io' (please refer to another post: [Forge ARKit: Cannot load model in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55802490/forge-arkit-cannot-load-model-in-unity)).

It seems for some components in the model it is visible but for some others it 's not, one thing I noticed is that some components has non-Unicode(Finnish) value in properties such as Type/Type name, not sure if that is the root-cause.

Can anyone help to check what can be wrong? I can upload the sample model.

[image: The downloaded model is incomplete, only some components are visible]

[image: What it should be like]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Having special characters in the model metadata should not affect the geometry in any way. If you don't mind, please send your sample model to forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com and we'll take a look.

Also, have you perhaps noticed any warnings in the Unity log output when importing the scene?

Comment: Yes I carefully checked and found that the encoding is not the cause. I will send you a mail with the model and my process. Thanks

Comment: I just sent the mail, there is no error message during the uploading or downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone running into a similar issue, there was a problem with how affine transforms from https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io were being parsed in Unity. If you're seeing similar issues (meshes in the scene having positions/rotations/scales all set to zeros), go to *Assets/Forge/CodeBase/InstanceTreeRequest.cs* and replace the `"AffineMatrix"` switch case with the following code:

```
case "AffineMatrix":
    Matrix4x4 mat = new Matrix4x4 ();

    var elements = node["mt"]["elements"].AsArray;
    mat.m00 = elements[0].AsFloat;
    mat.m10 = elements[1].AsFloat;
    mat.m20 = elements[2].AsFloat;
    mat.m01 = elements[3].AsFloat;
    mat.m11 = elements[4].AsFloat;
    mat.m21 = elements[5].AsFloat;
    mat.m02 = elements[6].AsFloat;
    mat.m12 = elements[7].AsFloat;
    mat.m22 = elements[8].AsFloat;

    mat.m03 = node["tr"]["x"].AsFloat;
    mat.m13 = node["tr"]["y"].AsFloat;
    mat.m23 = node["tr"]["z"].AsFloat;
    mat.m33 = 1.0f;

    obj.transform.localScale = ScaleFromMatrix (mat);
    obj.transform.rotation = RotationFromMatrix (mat);
    obj.transform.position = TranslationFromMatrix (mat);
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes this is the root-cause, I applied the fix and it's working well now! Thanks!

Comment: Hello, there, I would like to ask whether this fix has been included into some 'new version', as I checked there is still no new version so far. The lasted Unity package is still 'ForgeARKit-update-6-2018.1.unitypackage', while the scene preparation scripts here "http://forgetoolkit.com/#/scenePrepration" are still as same as many months ago...