# AR / VR Toolkit incomplete model from navisworks files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-navisworks

I have been looking for a way to optimize / reduce the mesh of my model to display large / detailed models on my mobile phone in AR.

By chance I found out that Navisworks automatically optimizes the mesh when importing the revit file, better than I did in Maya.
So I loaded the navisworks file on forge, translated it, created a scene and processed it.
When downloading the scene in unity, the model is not loaded completely.
This only happens with .nwc files. I also tested .rvt/.f3d./.obj/.fbx files formats.

Models in Viewer. On the left .nvc, on the right .rvt model.

[Autodesk Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXUIv.jpg)
[AR / VR Toolkit Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTTOP.png)

Already changed the code like described in this post:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440193/model-incomplete-when-loading-with-forge-ar-vr-toolkit).
Works for all file format except .nwc

Comment: If you could share the navisworks file with us via forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com, I would take a look and see what's going on there.

Comment: thanks for the support, email has been sent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the two file formats are handled slightly differently. In Revit, all meshes are positioned relatively to a shared "global offset", but in Navisworks, the meshes have real global offsets. In case of your .nwc file, the meshes are placed tens of millions of units from the origin, and Unity then fails to render them:

[image: Unity Inspector Panel]

We will take a look at handling these values better in AR/VR Toolkit, but in the meantime I'd suggest that you move the .nvc model closer to the origin.

Comment: Reset the origin fixed the problem. Thanks (y)