# Creating scene definition against beta server gets 422 error

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to use the Unity AR/VR Toolkit with a SVF file I've created by following the test-2legged script. My understanding from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55802490/forge-arkit-cannot-load-model-in-unity) answer is that the script needs to be updated to use the new server (https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io) and a URL-safe encoded URN everywhere. I've done that, but when I try to create the scene definition (PUT /arkit/v1/${urn}/scenes/${scene}) I get a 422 with a msg of "must be a valid Bearer token for the requested resource (TK1-003)" (I've tried giving the token all scopes listed in the Forge docs).

This works fine with the server in the non-modified test-2legged script. I'm operating on a file that's already in Forge so I'm not including the bucket, and I've experimented with including and not including the object ID; the default server (https://developer-api.autodesk.io) works fine with just an urn; the beta server I can't get to work no matter what I try.

I don't see any documentation for this endpoint so I'm not sure if it's use changed between the servers. As far as I can tell, in the toolkit I can't get SVF files created against the non-beta server (I get 404's for the meshes), so I'm assuming I should be on the beta server, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: It's possible the problem is that I'm combining 2-legged auth with an existing item. According to this (https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/11/forge-datamanagement-api-items-versions-and-attachments.html) 2-legged auth gets access to private buckets and objects, implying to me it doesn't have access to the bucket used to store the file I'm interested in. Only guessing, but that does square with the auth issue.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look into the source code and TK1-003 means that the Bearer token was either invalid, expired, and the token was missing the data:create data:write scoped for this operation. Note that in case, you call and API with an invalid token, the server bans you for couple of minutes.
If you still having issues, please let me know and I'll remote assist you.

Comment: I am getting this same error msg and the token is valid.